# Retrieving child value across random key -Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d22Vm.png)I want to retrieve temperature values that updating to Firebase by using random key over time. I want to show the temperature value in app according to real time data. I try to use addValueEventListner but seems like the value didnt manage to changes in real time. `public class SecondActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private DatabaseReference mDatebase;
private TextView mTempView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_b);
    mDatebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Region 1").child("Parameter Reading").child("temperature");
    mTempView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempvalue);


     mDatebase.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String name = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            mTempView.setText("Temperature, C: " + name);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });`}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way you are referring to your data is the problem.

**your data location is:**

hydroponic-monitoring-system / Region 1 / Parameter Reading / KzB1.../temperature

**The way you read your data**

Region 1 / Parameter Reading / temperature

so you skipped  the child (hydroponic-monitoring-system).

**The problem you face**

now the child (KzB1..) or (KzB2..) these are push keys which means you are not able to refer to them, because you don't know them they are pushed.

**Your possible solution is to loop through children like that:**

change the:

```
  mDatebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Region 1").child("Parameter Reading").child("temperature");
```

into this

```
  mDatebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("hydroponic-monitoring-system").child("Region 1").child("Parameter Reading");
```

and in your value event listener do this in onDatachange

```
       @Override
    public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

          //loop through the keys
         for  (DataSnapshot datasnap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

           String name = datasnap.child("temperature").getValue(String.class);
           mTempView.setText("Temperature, C: " + name);
         }



    }
```

and you should read now the temp at each level of push keys.

Comment: glad to help, make sure to accept so that  others know that it is correct.

Comment: is that possible to create another textView to show the previous value (temperature) once the reading is updated?